# How do I change wallpaper periodically using WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I am trying to change the wallpaper of Android, in some periodic interval.

I used WorkManager to run a worker, that downloads the wallpaper in the background and sets it.

As long as the app is running, the wallpaper is changed. When I close the wallpaper, it stops. I am using PeriodcWork in Workmanager.

This is my code

```
public class OneTimeWorker extends Worker {
Context context = getApplicationContext();
private String URL;
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    new FetchWallpaper().execute();
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
private class FetchWallpaper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String imageUrl="";
        Bitmap result = null;
        try
        {
            URL = "myurl.com";
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .build();
            Response responses = null;
            try {
                responses = client
                        .newCall(request)
                        .execute();
                String jsonData = responses.body().string();

                JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonData);
                JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(new Random().nextInt(jsonArr.length()));

                imageUrl = c.getString("wallpaper");

                result = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use [Android-Job by Evernote](https://github.com/evernote/android-job).

Internally uses WorkManager, provides smooth, nice - chained methods & reliability while it's easy to implement.

Automatically chooses between **JobManager/WorkManager/GCM/AlarmManager** to ensure that your code must execute.

I myself using this and it's good.

Comment: Does it work for Chinese ROM like Oxygen OS? I tried this evernote android-job but once app is removed from recent tray, the job no longer fires.

Comment: Did you test your app against these Chinese ROM? Like OS for Oneplus, Xiaomi, Huawei?

Comment: Checked OnePlus and Xiaomi

Comment: Thanks, will try once again. Is any special permission required to run the job in background even if app is closed? or should I enable "ignore battery optimization" in the app?

Comment: Battery optimization and doze mode maybe a problem... You'll get all code snippets and help at the github page & faq of the repo. Check updating code as well as disabling doze mode. Ensure that you're using `setUpdateCurrent(true)` also.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Toaster, will let you know once I solve or encounter any problem.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Ask again on any doubt.

Comment: Hi @Toaster, I used android-job by Evernote. As always, works on Stock Rom, tested in Nexus, Nokia phones, works perfectly fine, the job runs, not an issue. But testing on Onplus 5t doesn't work. The service doesn't run when the app is swiped from recent tray. But when I swipe on Stock ROM devices, still works. 

I have seen some apps achieving the same in Oneplus too.

This particular option. Do you know how to get this?

https://ibb.co/cN0XD9

Comment: Let me have some time, I'm gonna checking it.

Comment: hmm, did you see the image above? How to get that option?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that option.. I've got this two on my nokia 5(7.1.1) https://ibb.co/c5nJmU
https://ibb.co/kH4L0p

Comment: Ok, one thing.. test `STICKEY_SERVICE` then read this https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/services-the-life-with-without-and-worker-6933111d62a6  | Background is a war now .. you can check this too : https://exploitrme.wordpress.com/2018/06/02/how-to-make-broadcast-receiver-run-when-my-app-is-in-background/